# How to rerail closet door?

Tags: doors

One of my closet door springs detached from the little thing that moved on the rail.

How can I put it back in?

[image]

Comment: Im believe you lost a nylon roller that should be attached to that pin with the spring on it.

Comment: Take a look at the other door. Duplicate the setup from that one to this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the hole that the pin in the top of the door was in, the pin in the top of the door is spring loaded. Push it down so it can be relocated under the hole in needs to go back into and release it so it springs back up.

The door may need to be adjusted elsewhere to keep it from happening again.

Comment: Yes, and  note that the spring outside the nylon channel should be _inside_ it, as the other one is. There should be a spring on either side of the pin. It shouldn't be on the pin as it is now.